# XML Validation Apache Camel

Tags: java, xml, validation, apache-camel

Im trying to use the Camel Validation Component to validate an XML against an XSD.

```
<to uri="validator:validation_xsd/Schema.xsd" />
```

When I catch the SchemaValidationException and I get the errors .getErrors()
it just return a List of 1 element (just the first one).

Is is possible to validate the entire element and get all errors?.

The XML I'm trying to validate has almost 10.000 errors.

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible if the XML parser due to the first error would not be able to continue because the first error would effect continued processing. Camel is using standard JDK javax.xml.validation.Validator#validate(javax.xml.transform.Source, javax.xml.transform.Result) to validate, so maybe research how that works and what it can do in terms of attempting to validate the entire document. And maybe there is something we can add/improve in Camel.

Comment: Oh just spotted the class javadoc on org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler which says that if there is a fatalError then the parser may not continue. So maybe check if its a fatal error you have.

Comment: And is there a way to use my custom ErrorHandler?

Comment: Yeah sure see the component docs what you can configure